# Downloaded file with Google Drive API. Can't find it anywhere

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file with google drive api. The code gives no error but I can't find the file anywhere. 
This is the code

```
String fileId = "...";
  OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  try {
    service.files().export(fileId, "text/csv")
              .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Ceva nu a mers bine");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    System.out.println(outputStream == null);
```

Any ideea?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [example in Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads), I don't see any error with your code.

```
String fileId = "1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().export(fileId, "application/pdf")
        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

Make sure that you are using the correct [fileId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27108178/google-drive-api-android-how-to-obtain-a-drive-file-id) of the specific file you want to download.

You can check on these links: [How to get Google Drive file ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553989/how-to-get-google-drive-file-id), [How to download a file from google drive using drive api java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133026/how-to-download-a-file-from-google-drive-using-drive-api-java)